# Ac load line of a transistor

Tags: bjt

I understand dc load line : for a given collector arrangement it lists all the possible values of (V_ce, I_c). So I expected that the AC load line should be the line on which all possible AC values of (v_ce, i_ce) would stay. But it looks like this line deals with all pairs of superimposed (ac+dc) collector-emtter voltage and current, is this correct? Or is this something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you are right. For the ac load line, the dc value of the voltage across the capacitor in parallel to the emitter resistor must be also taken into consideration (superposition).

**Example**: Common emitter stage with Rc (collector resistor), Re (emitter resistor) and Ce in paralle to Re.

a) For Re=0 the ac load line is between Icmax=Vcc/Rc and Vcemax=Vcc. The slope of the load line is m=-1/Rc

b) If we add Re, the load line is between Icmax=Vcc/(Rc+Re) and Vcemax=Vcc. The slope has reduced to m=-1/(Rc+Re)

c) Now, if we add Ce in parallel to Re, we have a continous DC drop IeRe across Re and the load line is between Icmax=(Vcc-IeRe)/Rc and Vcemax=(Vcc-IeRe). The slope has increased again to m=-1/Rc.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the ac load line you also need to take capacitors into account. For example, a common practice is to add a capacitor in parallel with the emitter resistor in a simple common-emitter NPN amplifier.